# flutter firebase messaging - ios silent notifications not launching the app in background to process the notification through background service

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

in flutter logs , on sending a silent notification to the device the below log appears where push launch event is cancelled preventing app to be started in background to process the notification in fcm background service.

```
Dispatching low priority message: <xpc object>

<private> Delivering message from apsd: <private> 1020306858 <private>

<private> responding with an ack for message with guid <private>

<private> making delegate (<private>) calls to deliver message 1020306858 <private> for topic <private>

<private> calling <private> connection:didReceiveIncomingMessage:

<private> returned from <private> connection:didReceiveIncomingMessage:

Received incoming message on topic network.talker.app.dev at priority 1

Looking up connection on peer: 11431c0   found <private>

<private> informed that <private> acknowledges incoming message with guid <private>

<private> Removing incoming message with guid <private>

<private> _schedulePendingWorkUpdate

APSMessageStore - APSIncomingMessageRecordDeleteMessageForGUID <private>

Received remote notification request F1E6-BBE1 [ hasAlertContent: 0, hasSound: 0 hasBadge: 0 hasContentAvailable: 1 hasMutableContent: 0 ]

Deliver push notification F1E6-BBE1

Request DUET delivers content-available push notification to application

SUBMITTING: <private>

Not delivering user visible notification F1E6-BBE1 because it has no alert, sound or badge

Not delivering user visible push notification F1E6-BBE1 [ error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1401 "Notification has no user visible content" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notification has no user visible content} ]

Submitted Activity: com.apple.pushLaunch.{{bundle id}} at priority 5 <private>

Push not allowed for <private>

Daemon Canceling Activities: {(

   com.apple.pushLaunch.{{bundle id}}

)}

CANCELED: com.apple.pushLaunch.{{bundle id}} at priority 5 <private>!
```

in main.dart file in the main function initializeFirebase function is
called .

```
Future initializeFirebase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  NotificationSettings settings = await 
     FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
  announcement: true,
  carPlay: true,
  criticalAlert: true,
);
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(
    _onAppInTerminatedNotificationHandler, // This Callback must be static
  );

  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
}

Future<void> _onAppInTerminatedNotificationHandler(
  RemoteMessage message,
) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print('A new terminated Push Notification Received');
  await NotificationManager.instance.showLocalNotification(message);
}
```

my appdelegate file

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
   Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
   super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included permission request like this for iOS

```
NotificationSettings settings =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
  announcement: true,
  carPlay: true,
  criticalAlert: true,
);
```

Comment: the result is still same

Comment: Please add your codes

Comment: added the code where firebase is initialized and background handler is added

Comment: Have you also added googleservicesinfo.plist through xcode?

Comment: yes, silent notifications work fine when app is in background state, it doesnt work when app is in terminated state.

Comment: How did you invoke initialiseFirebase method? In stateless or stateful widget? Also did you add the necessary codes in appdelegate file?

Comment: i have added the app delegate file in the description too.

Comment: Have you also registered key in developer.apple.com and added this key in firebase?

Comment: yes i have done that too.

Comment: Is the app downloaded from app store? It uses apn key to push the notification.. try it from test flight

Comment: Any updates here?